# I knew I have never been your enemy or I knew I had never been your enemy?

Tags: perfect-constructions

I always struggle with "I knew" sentences, because I'm completely incapable of understanding what tense should follow it. For example

> I knew I have never been your enemy.

or

> I knew I had never been your enemy.

In a situation where I'm still not this person's enemy, which tense should I use? Present perfect or past perfect?

Comment: You can put the _I knew_ part aside and just think about whether you _had been_ or _have been_ enemies. Then add _I knew_ before that.

Answer (score 1):

It should be I knew I *had* never been your enemy, or even just I knew I wasn't ever your enemy. If you were using present tense, you'd say I know I have never been your enemy.